# Merge replication - corrupt row continually trying to INSERT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, merge-replication

We have "push" SQL replication sent up, with one publisher and three subscribers. Two of the three are working fine, but one is continually causing trouble. I went through the pain and heartache of reinitialising the subscription at the weekend, and just a few days later it's stuck again.

This time, the error I'm seeing in replmerg.log (after turning up the verbosity) is:

> The merge process could not replicate one or more INSERT statements to
>   the 'Publisher'. A stored procedure failed to execute. Troubleshoot by
>   using SQL Profiler.

I've tracked this down to a single table in the database: for some reason, an obviously corrupt row is continually trying to be INSERTed into the table, with a rowguid of `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. `DBCC CHECKDB` shows no sign of corruption.

Here's the row:

[image]

If I try to get rid of the bad row on the Publisher:

```
delete from mytable
where rowguid like '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

I get the error:

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Procedure
>   MSmerge_del_590C419D78ED4A36A40292C23CF5F67B, Line 68 Cannot insert
>   duplicate key row in object 'dbo.MSmerge_tombstone' with unique index
>   'uc1MSmerge_tombstone'. The duplicate key value is (3095029,
>   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000). The statement has been
>   terminated.

If I manually remove the row from `MSmerge_tombstone`, it comes back after the next replication cycle (which is continuous, so typically 60 seconds later).

I **really** don't want to have to reinitialise this subscription again. Is there any way of purging this set of corrupt transactions out of the "queue", or otherwise returning the replication back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to hack my way around the issue, so I'll leave this here for posterity and in case anyone else has the problem. I've no doubt this is an extremely bad idea, and will cause my whole server to implode, but it has got replication firing again.

The `msmerge_contents` table seems to contain the "queued" UPDATEs and INSERTs, and it's one or more of the latter that seems to be causing the problem. So I did

```
delete from MSmerge_contents
where tablenick=xxx
```

... where `xxx` is the integer identity of the table from the other replication tables. This cleared out a couple of thousand rows, I restarted the agent, and after a bit of processing everything was back to normal. Fortunately, the table in question didn't contain anything too vital, so I don't need to worry about integrity too much.

Again, this is undoubtedly Not The Way To Do It, but it's appeared to work for me.

Comment: I'm curious if you could have edited the merge subscription to explicitly ignore the "corrupted" row, waited for a cycle to complete, fixed the row and then remove the filter.